# Laravel Oauth2 multiple grants

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I'm fairly new to Oauth2 and it seems I'm stuck.

To protect our API, we use OAuth2. We have a lot of calls that contain information based on an account, se we use the `password` grant in OAuth.

But, I also have to protect my *registration* call, so only registered applications with valid client_id and client_secret can use that call. So, after reading a while, it seemed that I needed to use the `client_credentials` grant for those calls.

But now, I have absolutely no idea how I can define witch call should be using `password` of `client_credentials`.

Am I thinking wrong and is it impossible to use a specific grant for a specific call, or how can I define when to use what grant?

FYI: I'm using Laravel5.1 and [Luca Degasperi's Laravel OAuth2 server](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel)

Thanks!

Comment: Which client-types will access the api?

Comment: an Android app and a iOs app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you won't limit calls or routes to specific grant types and for [several reasons](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20009) it's nearly impossible to limit the client-application access via oauth grants.

So as a rule of thumb you should only expose the endpoints the user is allowed to access doesen't matter which client is used.

Further more I would prefer the **client credentials** or **owner credentials** grant, it's better in facts of usability and security (Change Password, Remove Access for specific apps, ...) more about the different [grants](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Choosing-a-Grant).

Comment: And how do I know which user in the application is requesting his profile data (for example)? Adding a parameter with the user_id that's requested doesn't seem that safe to me...

Comment: The token(s) are linked to the user_id so you can access the user data via Auth::user().